# How to strikethrough text on a list element when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm super new to JS, HTML, and CSS. I've looked up many answers but can't quite understand the context when applied to my situation. Button 2 is what needs the onClick function, but I'm not sure how to implement the strikethrough aspect. Thank you!

My JS goes as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
            let text = document.getElementById("text-box").value;
            let li = document.createElement("li");
            li.id = "liId";
            li.innerText = text;
            document.getElementById("unordered-list").appendChild(li);
            
            let button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerText = "X";
            button.setAttribute = ("id", "b1");
            li.appendChild(button);
            button.addEventListener("click", () => li.parentNode.removeChild(li));
            document.getElementById("unordered-list").appendChild(li);
            
            let button2 = document.createElement("button");
            button2.innerText = "Done";
            button2.id = "b2";
            li.appendChild(button2);
           
            li.appendChild(button);
            li.appendChild(button2);
    });
    document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("liId").style = "text-decoration: line-through;"
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>My First Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <header id="to-do-box">
            <h1>To-Do List</h1>
            <div id="top-half">
                <form>    
                <input type="text" id="text-box" placeholder="Add an item!">
                <button type="button" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" id="clear-field-btn">Clear field</button>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="ul">
            <ul id="unordered-list"></ul>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fetch the element of interest and add the `text-decoration: line-through;` property to it when you want to do it. For example when you click the mentioned button. You can either add an eventlistener for the button or add an onclick function to trigger the action.

Comment: I tried this, but the text automatically has a strikethrough after it appears in the list.
```button.addEventListener("click", () => li.parentNode.appendChild(li));
            document.getElementById("unordered-list").appendChild(li).style.textDecoration = 'line-through';```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by implementing an event listener that activates on button click. This will delete the first list element that is shown.

```js
   document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
            let text = document.getElementById("text-box").value;
            let li = document.createElement("li");
            li.setAttribute = ("id", "list");
            li.id = "liId";
            li.innerText = text;
            document.getElementById("unordered-list").appendChild(li);
            
            let button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerText = "X";
            button.setAttribute = ("id", "b1");
            li.appendChild(button);
            button.addEventListener("click", () => li.parentNode.removeChild(li));
            document.getElementById("unordered-list").appendChild(li);
            
            let button2 = document.createElement("button");
            button2.innerText = "Done";
            button2.id = "b2";
            button2.classList.add('buttonClass');
           
            
            li.appendChild(button2);
           
            li.appendChild(button);
            li.appendChild(button2);
            
document.querySelectorAll('.buttonClass').forEach(item => {

             item.addEventListener('click', event => {
               change()
})})});


function change() {

      document.querySelectorAll("#b2").forEach(item => {
          item.parentNode.style = "text-decoration: line-through;"

})}

document.getElementById("clear-field-btn").addEventListener('click', event => {

document.querySelectorAll("#b2").forEach(item => {
          item.parentNode.remove();
})
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<header id="to-do-box">
            <h1>To-Do List</h1>
            <div id="top-half">
                <form>    
                <input type="text" id="text-box" placeholder="Add an item!">
                <button type="button" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" id="clear-field-btn">Clear field</button>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="ul">
            <ul id="unordered-list"></ul>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind though, this will only work for one of the list elements, if you want to discard all of the list elements if the user has multiple, you will need to utilize a `forEach` function.

Comment: Hey! It's not actually "clear-field-btn" in HTML that I want to access, instead it's "button2" with an ID of "b2". Does this logic still apply? I tried implementing your suggestion but I got an error `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at window.onload`

Comment: I also noticed that you included `li.id = "liId"` for my first button. Why is this?

Comment: Could you show a demo of all the code that you have so I can see if I can fix the problem? I just created another id so I could call upon it in `document.getElementById`

Comment: I updated it. Let me know if you'd like CSS as well! I appreciate your help

Comment: Alright I updated the code, sorry for the late response, tell me if it does not work.

Comment: I also added functionality for the clear field button